# How to convert local firestore log files into something more readable like json?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to convert the persistence data that Firestore saves locally into something like a json object that I can easily iterate through (incase of upload failure (such as a device restart mid-upload)).

This is what i've tried so far:

```
private func getFirebaseDoc() {

    if let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) {
        guard let temp = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent("firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/{*redacted*}/main").path) else { fatalError("haha idiot") }
        for temp2 in temp {
            if temp2.contains("log"){
                print(temp2)
                let dataTemp = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent("firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/{*redacted*}/main/\(temp2)"))

                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataTemp!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
                print(json)
                print(dataTemp)
            }
        }
        //            let haha = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString))
        //            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: haha!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
        print(temp)
    } else {
        print("major failure")
    }
}
```

Obviously JSONSerialization isn't possible but I can't seem to figure out the best way to convert it into something that I can then properly read through to look for that document's identification (that I set when sending to firestore)

Maybe I can convert the data object to a firestore object then somehow convert it to json or something? Not sure :/

Data sample example:

```
Â
SË·Â
SË·Â
SË·ÇüHò· 
collection_parentAssignIDh
document_mutationMhNFMzBV1DPqeOwC48L1K59wyuE3¾AssignID¾*redactedhardwareID*-
mutationMhNFMzBV1DPqeOwC48L1K59wyuE3§

kprojects/*redactedprojectname*/databases/(default)/documents/AssignID/*redactedidentification*£
Device Information2
5

hardwareId'$*redactedhardwareID*

deviceIDX

latitude    ¾ý§Üz:E@

    longitude   ô¹XYÙQÀ
```

Comment: Show a data sample.

Comment: @ElTomato added data sample